ReSharper Test Runner Ignores `.runsettings` File, But Visual Studio Test Runner Works
I am facing an issue where the .runsettings file is not affecting the execution of my tests when I run them through the ReSharper test runner. However, when I run the tests using Visual Studio’s built-in test runner, the settings in the .runsettings file are applied correctly.
Here’s my .runsettings file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <TestCaseFilter>TestCategory != MyCategory</TestCaseFilter> 
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>

When using the Visual Studio test runner, the TestCaseFilter is applied as expected, and tests with the category MyCategory are excluded from the test run. But when running the same tests through ReSharper’s test runner, the filter is ignored, and all tests are executed.
Relevant Settings:

ReSharper settings:

➡️ And I tried both options (to use .runsettings selected in VS UI and using specific test settings file)

Visual Studio settings:



Environment Details:

Target Framework: .NET 8
Test Framework: MSTest
Visual Studio version: 17.11.4
ReSharper version: 2024.2.5

I tried configuring the .runsettings file with a TestCaseFilter to exclude tests with the category MyCategory. I expected ReSharper’s test runner to apply this filter and exclude those tests from the run, just like Visual Studio's test runner does. However, ReSharper’s test runner ignored the .runsettings file, and all tests were executed, including those in MyCategory.

Hello, I have reproduced the issue, but unfortunately, I haven't identified the cause yet. However, there is another way to help you exclude certain tests using categories. After adding all the tests to the session, you can group them by categories and select "Remove selected tests" to exclude the corresponding tests.

Thanks! I actually already did this WA...

Regrettably, specifying TestCaseFilter via runsettings is not supported in R# yet. There's an open report about this: RSRP-498774 TestCaseFilter in .runsettings ignored, please upvote the issue.
